# Receiving MISO data using ioctl and spi_ioc_transfer

Tags: pi-3, spi, c++

Good day all,

I am new to RPI and have been learning as I go. A few questions when interfacing with an SPI device using c++.

The data sheet https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Murata%20PDFs/SCA61T.pdf

1) I believe this is SPI mode 0 correct?

2) How do I read out an 11 bit read for the RDAX value after sending my command through the MOSI?

I do not understand how I would work with the MISO data when it is not byte aligned. It sends 11 bits, but I can only receive it into a 2 byte array(16 bits). I guess I am confused on the overall process. I have used http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/spi/using-the-spi-interface as a starting point.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 11 bit response is part of an 19 bit sequence (8 bit command + 11 bit data).

The simplest thing to do is transfer 3 bytes (24 bits) and ignore the last 5 received bits.

If you send three bytes you receive 3 bytes.

```
      Byte 1            Byte 2            Byte 3
| C C C C C C C C | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | sent
| - - - - - - - - | D D D D D D D D | D D D - - - - - | received
```

value = (byte 2 << 3) + (byte 3 >> 5)

Comment: That appears to have done the trick, but I don't understand why shifting the bits to the left 3 times gives me my answer? Wont you lose information doing that if the MSB -> 3 has information in it?

Comment: @LanetRino The bit shift doesn't restrict the answer to a byte.  If you prefer think of it as multiply by eight (and divide by 32 for the >> 5).  Use multiply and divide if you prefer, it's just personal taste.

Comment: No no, I get bit shifting. I mean, if I have a byte 0110 0010(98) and shift << 3, the resulting number is 0001 0000(16). Why does this give me the information i need? Why am I shifting(multiplying or dividing), to interpret the received information? Please bear with me, I am new to EE

Comment: I don't understand the question.  11 bits are returned.  It's convenient to convert the 11 binary bits to a single decimal value.

Comment: Why does this convert it to a decimal value? What does the untouched data represent, and why does this turn it into a decimal value? I plugged in the returned RDAX value into the formula and am getting the correct angle, but I don't understand why I first need to shift bits around.

Comment: You need to read up about the SPI protocol and then look at the representation of numbers in computers.  These broad questions are beyond the scope of comments.